# HTML selected not preselecting Values

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I'm stuck with, what I think, should be something basic. But i can't, for the love of anything, get it to work.

```
       :
echo "<tr><td>Aktiv</td><td>";
echo "<select class=left size=1 name=active>";
echo "<option value=1>aktiv</option>";
echo '<option value=0 selected>inaktiv</option>';
echo "</select>";
echo "</td></tr>";
       :
```

I just want to create a dropdown and preselect the "inaktiv" option.
The funny part is, when using it on my Work-PC, this will still preselect "aktiv".
When i throw this in any kind of other thing, even the most basic online "compiler", it will do just fine.
Are there mybe any kind of kompatibility issues with this on like older versions of Firefox or something like that?

Comment: Not that I know of, but why not `?><tr><td>Aktiv</td><td>
<select class="left" size="1" name="active">
<option value="1">aktiv</option>
<option value="0" selected>inaktiv</option>
</select>
echo "</td></tr><? ...`

Comment: *"When i throw this in any kind of other thing, even the most basic online "compiler", it will do just fine."* then this is not reproducible. You might have an issue with your server/work-pc, thats a task for your admin.

Comment: You should really get into the habit of putting quotes around your parameter values as @mplungjan hinted at, and be consistent with which quotes you use. `echo "<select class='left' size='1' name='active'>";` for example. Won't matter until one of your parameters has a space in it.

Comment: @droopsnoot/@mplungjan: Will do, should make everything more readable.

As a fun fact, my collegue now wrote to me, that, up until now, everything worked just fine, so this is getting even more confusing for me.